# php decrease value on multi array

Tags: php, arrays

Hello i'am novice and i must to decrease the value in the array, but with some difficulty, if somebody can give me the direction of my issue thank in advance.

I have an array of my product with $id => $quantity

```
array:4 [▼
  43 => 3;
  44 => 2;
  47 => 2;
  51 => 2;
]
```

This property represents a cart of product for restaurant this cart can be divided by 3 categories like Entree, Dish, Dessert.

Entree

```
array:2 [▼
  43 => 3;
  44 => 2;
]
```

Dish

```
array:1[▼
  47 => 2;
]
```

Dessert

```
array:1[▼
  51 => 2;
]
```

If I add a menu I must decrease one Entree, one Dish and one Dessert.
i understand how to decrease an array like this :

```
$cart[$idEntree]--;
```

But if I have 2 or more product how I can select the id for decrease the value in one product an after the product value = 0 decrease the next product.

for exemple i will decrease 4 menu to the Entree Array:

```
array:2 [▼
  43 => 3;
  44 => 2;
]
```

and after that i have:

```
array:2 [▼
  43 => 0;
  44 => 1;
]
```

if you can help me thank you .

Answer (score 1):

This should work in your case:

```
$products_to_subtract = 4;

foreach ($array as $id => $value) {
    while($value && $products_to_subtract)
    {
        $array[$id] = --$value;
        $products_to_subtract--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to loop over the array `foreach`.

```php
$selections = [
    43 => 3,
    44 => 2
];

foreach ($selections as $key => $value) {
    if ($value > 0) {
        $selections[$key] -= 1;
    } else {
        $selections[$key] = 0;
    }
}

var_dump($selections);

// array(2) {
//  [43]=>
//  int(2)
//  [44]=>
//  int(1)
//}
```

Comment: They want `[ 43 => 0; 44 => 1]` your output is `[ 43 =>2; 44 => 1]` ?

Comment: For each selections you soustact 1 at every $key at the same time. i want to soustract 4 to all the groupe, not 4 at the first and second ....If i decrease only one i would like only 43=>3 or 44=>2 is soustract by one,  i try this solution without succes but many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply using `foreach` with `while` loops:
[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/GMGIi)

```php
$Entree = [
    43 => 3,
    44 => 2
];
$i = 1;
$count = 4;
foreach ($Entree as $id => $value) {
    while ($i <= $count) {
        $Entree[$id] -= $i;
        $i++;
        $count--;
        if($Entree[$id] === 0)
            break 2; // skip both loops
    }
}
print_r($Entree);
```

**Result**

```php
Array
(
    [43] => 0
    [44] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For my solution, I place a variable who is decrese by every loop for not decrease too much product.

```
$quantityPlatLoop = $quantityMenuVerif;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $quantityMenuVerif ;$i++){
            foreach($platCalculQuantity as $idPlatQuantity => $platQuantity){
                if($cart[$idPlatQuantity] >= 1 && $quantityPlatLoop >= 1){
                    $cart[$idPlatQuantity]--;
                    $quantityPlatLoop--;

                }

            }

        }
```